# How to access tag attribute in spacebar

Tags: meteor, spacebars

How to get attribute value from tag like width, color, value ...

```
<template>
   {{#if body.width > 979px }}
      {{> tmp1 }}
   {{else}}
      {{> tmp2 }}
   {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="tmp1">...</template>
<template name="tmp2">...</template>
```

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried?

Comment: the only way i found is to make dynamic template then in the onRendered event get these value using js but am stuck in the window resize event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found that there's no spacebars proper solution and the best option is to use js code.

**So here's the code:**

```
Session.set("width", $(window).innerWidth());
window.onresize = function () { Session.set("width", $(window).innerWidth()); };

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({ 'dynamicTemplateName': function () { return Session.get("width"); } });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access tag attributes directly from Spacebars template. You need to create a template helper for that.

```
Template.templateXY.helpers({
   bigBody: function() {
      return $("body").width() > 979;
   }
});
```

then you use it like this:

```
<template name="templateXY">
   {{#if bigBody}}
      {{> tmp1}}
   {{else}}
      {{> tmp2}}
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

**UPDATE**: for the helper to recompute on window resize event, you need to modify it a little bit. You can use a Dependency object for this.

```
Template.templateXY.onCreated(function() {
   // create a dependency
   this.resizeDep = new Dependency();
});

Template.templateXY.onRendered(function() {
   let tmpl = this;
   // invalidate the dependency on resize event (every 200ms)
   $(window).on("resize.myEvent", _.throttle(function() {
      tmpl.resizeDep.changed();
   }, 200));
});

Template.templateXY.helpers({
   bigBody: function() {
      // recompute when the dependency changes
      Template.instance().resizeDep.depend();
      return $("body").width() > 979;
   }
})

Template.templateXY.onDestroyed(function() {
   $(window).unbind("resize.myEvent");
});
```

Other possible solution would be to store the window width to a ReactiveVar (which is a reactive data source itself) and use .on("resize", fn) to change the ReactiveVar

Comment: Will it be updated when the body width change for example when the window is resized ?

Comment: Nope, I updated the answer with a reactive version. See if it helps you anyhow.